# Returning all keys that have the same value in a dictionary in python

Tags: loops, dictionary

I am trying to return a list of recipes (the keys) that meet certain the input value in Python 3.7 using Spyder. I am able to get the first value from the dictionary, but I cannot append any more to the list.

```
recipes = {'Fixate Pasta E Fagioli' : '1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Vegan Quinoa with Winter Veggies' : 
'1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Balsamic Mushroom Toast' : '1G1Y1t' }

matching_recipes = []

def get_recipe(cont):
    for recipe, containers in recipes.items():
        if cont == containers:
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)
            return matching_recipes
    return 'no matching recipe'

print(get_recipe('1G1Y1t'))
```

I get: ['Fixate Pasta E Fagioli']

Why won't it iterate through and append the other recipes to the list? I am clearly a novice at Python, so maybe I don't understand why it won't continue to iterate and append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you return the `matching_recipes` immediately when `cont==containers`,so it will break the loop.I change the return position
- the `matching_recipes` should be a function variable,not a global variable

```py
recipes = {'Fixate Pasta E Fagioli' : '1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Vegan Quinoa with Winter Veggies' : 
'1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Balsamic Mushroom Toast' : '1G1Y1t' }


def get_recipe(cont):
    matching_recipes = []
    for recipe, containers in recipes.items():
        if cont == containers:
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)
    if len(matching_recipes)>0:
        return matching_recipes
    else:
        return 'no matching recipe'

print(get_recipe('1G1Y1t'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The code worked perfectly.

Comment: I am very glad that help you.could you mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

- The reason "Why won't it iterate through and append the other recipes to the list?" you can see @nay's answer.
- There is a simple way with `list comprehension` to do it.

#### code:

```
recipes = {'Fixate Pasta E Fagioli' : '1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Vegan Quinoa with Winter Veggies' : 
'1G1Y1t' , 'Fixate Balsamic Mushroom Toast' : '1G1Y1t',"test":"123","foo":"bar","hello":"bar" }

def get_recipe(value):
    return [k for k,v in recipes.items() if v == value]

print(get_recipe('1G1Y1t'))
print(get_recipe('bar'))
print(get_recipe('foo'))
```

#### result:

```
['Fixate Pasta E Fagioli', 'Fixate Vegan Quinoa with Winter Veggies', 'Fixate Balsamic Mushroom Toast']
['foo', 'hello']
[]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code which worked. I am looking for the response of "no matching recipe" when something doesn't match. I do like the simplicity of the code.